# WSO2 IS 5.6.0 and OpenID Connect Claims

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, openid-connect, claims, wso2-identity-server

Hello friendly StackOverflowers,

we are using WSO2 Identity Server 5.6.0 and are trying to use OpenID Connect to secure applications.

I followed https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Configuring+Claims+for+a+Service+Provider and created custom external oidc claims mapping to local claims. I also added the oidc claims to the oidc file in the registry.
It appears though, that the documentation is not fully up to date as there is an additional dropdown in 5.6.0 with the Service Provider Claim Dialect.

When we try to login, the login itself works, but the claims are not attached to the id token correctly. Even though the claim manager was able to retreive the claims, as I see in the logfile.

I tried a couple different variations (Custom Claim Dialects, Local Claim Dialect and also choosing just the Service Provider Claim Dialect), but nothing worked.

Interestingly: 
If I choose a claim as the subject, and the consent is given by the user, the claim is attached to the id token - even if I remove it from the subject again.
I managed to get all the claims working, by choosing them as the subject, one by one, and giving consent during the login. 
This however only works for this particular user.

Anyone got a pointer to how I have to configure the OpenID claims in 5.6.0? In 5.3.0 they did work with the same configuration.

Regards,
Mat

Comment: I have just did a quick test, I could able to get the local claims through id token by selecting the claims through Requested Claims. If you could, can you share the logs regarding the claims and share the screenshots of your configuration?

Comment: Would be helpful to see the output, after https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Adding+Logs+for+Tokens was activated.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by completely removing everything from the oidc claims, except for sub, updated_at and our own claims. After that I was able to use the oidc claims. However, I do think that this is just a fluke of our system.